# Wonder why while not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I expected the loop to run 3 times. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

```js
var text = "";
var x = 123;
while (x > 0) {
  text += "<br>The number is " + x;
  x=x/10;
  
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is print the number first than remove last digit.If that is the case than, Here `x/10` do not return an Integer number that is why the loop is executing more than once. Try the following:

```js
var text = "";
var x = 123;
while (x > 0) {
  text += "<br>The number is " + x;
  x=Math.floor(x/10); 
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check against `1` instead of zero, because a positive number divided by another positive number is always greater than zero.

```js
var text = "";
var x = 123;
while (x > 1) {
    text += "<br>The number is " + x;
    x /= 10;
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```